# PHP internationalization with intl

Tags: php, localization, gettext, intl, php-gettext

I'm looking for a good way to internationalize an PHP application. My conclusions so far, is that I'll not use `gettext` (keeps failing randomly, bad implementation of cache with `lighttpd` I guess) and `Zend` is not a option to me.

I'm very interested in the [PHP internationalization functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) introduced in PHP 5.3. But I'm not so sure if it's the tool for the job. I didn't find any article about using this guys for app localization, but it seems that a [BundleResource](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.resourcebundle.php) is exactly what I want.

Can someone here confirm with it's the way to go and how to organize/create/populate/use a resource bundle? The official documentation is too superficial (eg [ResourceBundle::create](http://www.php.net/manual/en/resourcebundle.create.php)) or  I'm missing something here.

Otherwise, I'll use arrays as a last resort. aargh!

Comment: There're some gettext clones in pure PHP that work on top of regular PO catalogues. You can at least take benefit from tools like Poedit.

Comment: Have you been through this documentation? http://userguide.icu-project.org/

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario None of these tools seemd "mature" enough. So I didn't even tried. Do you recommend some?

Comment: @edmondscommerce So `intl` comes from this? It seems quite challenging to learn it all and don't to much time to spare, unfortunately.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Please, I'm desperate...

Comment: I really have nothing else to say, thus my lack of further comments. Certainly, none of those PHP third-party libraries are mature (most are not even maintained). I've only used them as fallback for PHP set-ups where gettext will refuse working. I've never used ICU either.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario Ok, I understand. Damn you PHP!111